# Remove and Replace all the header sequences

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics

kindly your comment highly appreciated

have more than 4k header sequences look like:

```
>LTR_retrotransposon100_Gypsy? 
cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta

>LTR_retrotransposon10011_ERVK 
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat

>LTR_retrotransposon10011_ERVL-MaLR 
    taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat

>LTR_retrotransposon100_Copia 
    cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta
```

I would like to use awk or sed to remove everything between the underscore, including the underscore and replace it with /

and the target output could be:

```
>LTR/Gypsy?
ctcagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaacctaaatgtcttatcaatag atgactggataaaggagctgtggtatatctatacaatggaataccatcagccataaaaaa gaataaaatattgccatttgcagcaacatggatggacctggagattatcattctaaggga agtaagccagaaagagaaagaaaaataccatatgatatcacttatatgtggaggtaaaaa aaaaaaaaaagacacaaatcaatttatttgcaaaacatacaTGGActttcagacatagaa

>LTR/ERVL-MaLR
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat



>LTR/ERVK
    taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat

>LTR/Copia 
    cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta
```

Comment: 3. What change do you want applied between the input and the output - is it just to replace { `_retrotransposon`, some digits, and an optional `_` } with the `/` character? If not, [please tell us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/567194/edit).

Comment: i edited the question thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
$ sed 's:_.*_:/:' file
>LTR/Gypsy?
cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta

>LTR/ERVL-MaLR
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat
```

or if you prefer awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/_.*_/,"/")}1' file
>LTR/Gypsy?
cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta

>LTR/ERVL-MaLR
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat
```

Comment: Dear Thank you for your response, kindly check the updated question

Comment: Did you try my solution? Looks to me like it'd work. If it doesn't, tell us in what way.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
sed -e 's:_retrotransposon10011_:/:g ; s:_retrotransposon100_:/:g' < input > output
```

Tests:

```
$ cat input
LTR_retrotransposon100_Gypsy?
cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta

LTR_retrotransposon10011_ERVL-MaLR
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat

$ sed -e 's:_retrotransposon10011_:/:g ; s:_retrotransposon100_:/:g' < input
LTR/Gypsy?
cgtgcaccccaatgttcatagcagcactatttacaatagccaagacatggaaacaaccta aatgtcctttgacaggtgactggataaagaagctgtggtatatttatacaatggaatgct actcagccataaaaaagaataagataatgccatttacagcaacatggatagacctggaga atgttattctaagtgaagtaagccagaaagaaaaagaaaaataccatatgctatcactta

LTR/ERVL-MaLR
taatttgaaaagatacatgcaacccaatgttcatagcagcattatttacaattgccaaga tatggaagcaatctaagtgtccatcaacagatgaatggagagagaagatgtggtatatat acaataaaatactattctgtcataaaaatgaataaaattctgccatttgcaacaacatgg atagacctggagggtattatgctatgtgaaataagtcagacagagaaagacatatactat
```

If in the input file the strings between the two underscore (`_`) characters can have a variable number of characters the following sed with a regular expression can solve the problem:

```
sed -e 's:^\(.*\)_.*_\(.*\)$:\1/\2:' < input > output
```

Explanation:

- parentheses in the first part define groups (strings in fact) that can be reused in the second part
- `\1`, `\2`, etc. in the second part are references to the i-th group captured in the first part (the numbering starts with 1)

Answer (score 0):

Its not awk, but shouldn't `sed -e 's,^LTR_retrotransposon100_,LTR/,'` just work?

Comment: when trying sed -e 's,^LTR_retrotransposon100_,LTR/,' sequence.fa /////// ITS not working

Comment: What do you mean "_it's not working_"? An error? No output? We're not with you - you have to tell us!

Comment: the output is the same as the input

Comment: The target input lines don't start with `LTR` they start with `>LTR`.